# Access Violation in calling glGenBuffers()

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, glfw, glew

I'm trying to develop a game engine and was adding a batched rendering feature. I have 2 problems here,

1. Have some unusual **access violation errors**.

   I initialized the Buffer classes as a member variable of the Renderer class

   ```cpp
   Scope<VertexBuffer> vertex = CreateScope<OpenGLVertexBuffer>(ME_MAX_VERTEX_BUFFER_SIZE, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
   Scope<IndexBuffer> index = CreateScope<OpenGLIndexBuffer>(ME_MAX_INDEX_BUFFER_SIZE, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
   ```

   The `Scope` meantioned above refers `unique_ptr` and `CreateScope` refers `make_unique`
   The code file:
   Header: https://github.com/VikramSGIT/MarsEngine/blob/master/MarsEngine/src/RenderAPI/OpenGL/OpenGLRenderer.cpp
   CPP:  https://github.com/VikramSGIT/MarsEngine/blob/master/MarsEngine/src/RenderAPI/OpenGL/OpenGLRenderer.cpp
   The constructor of the Vertex Buffer classes (Index Buffer Class Have similar constructor)

   ```cpp
   OpenGLVertexBuffer::OpenGLVertexBuffer(const unsigned int& size, const unsigned int& mode)
       :Emptybuffer(true)
   {
       ME_PROFILE_TRACE_CALL();

       GLLogCall(glGenBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
       GLLogCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_RendererID));
       GLLogCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, nullptr, mode));
   }
   ```

   Had Access Violation excactly at `glGenBuffers(1 ,&m_RendererID)`.
   Even doudle checked that i had called `glewInit()` after `glfwMakeCurrentContext(window)`.
2. When I tried to add `glewInit()` inside the above OpenGLVertexBuffer class constructor. There came another unusual problem where `glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_RendererID)` is **stuck unterminated!!**

   ```cpp
   OpenGLVertexBuffer::~OpenGLVertexBuffer()
   {
       ME_PROFILE_TRACE_CALL();

       GLLogCall(glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_RendererID));
   }
   ```

   Then I ran the same model of code in VS Code, Ran Smooth. So this concludes that I had no driver problems.

   > And to be noted I didn't get an output (was not included as I'm not sure with logic) on my screen and ImGui ran smoothly. But I ran breakpoints over every part of the logic, buffers filled up as expected ba can fain waz goin wroonng :(

Link to my Github repo: https://github.com/VikramSGIT/MarsEngine

Comment: Looking at your code, I can't find where there is any call to `make_unique`. Is it indirect or obscured? Where is the `unique_ptr` stored exactly? It looks like you actually try to store a `shared_ptr` to a `unique_ptr`. Was that intentional?!

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for responding!!! and im really sorry, actually i forget to meantion `make_unique` and `unique_prt` is refers `Scope` whereas `make_shared` and `shared_prt' refers `Ref`. _It looks like you actually try to store a shared_ptr to a unique_ptr. Was that intentional?!_  No, not intentional, it was a bug!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
using Ref = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template<typename T>
using Scope = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Ref<T> CreateRef(Args&& ... args) { return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args (args)...); }

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
Scope<T> CreateScope(Args&& ...args) { return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args> (args)...); }
```

Your `CreateScope` function creates a `unique_ptr`, but your `Scope` object stores a `shared_ptr`. I suspect the problem is this:

```
template<typename T>
using Scope = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

Which was supposed to be:

```
template<typename T>
using Scope = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

Comment: I've updated the repo( removed the bug you mentioned). This is the file which contain the code, You been looking for: Header:  [link](https://github.com/VikramSGIT/MarsEngine/blob/master/MarsEngine/src/RenderAPI/OpenGL/OpenGLRenderer.h) CPP: [link](https://github.com/VikramSGIT/MarsEngine/blob/master/MarsEngine/src/RenderAPI/OpenGL/OpenGLRenderer.cpp). And Thank You!!